# Methods to model mutations performed by functions

Tags: design, architecture, model, grammar

Given a set of interfaces, objects implementing those interfaces, and functions that use those objects, what methods exist to model mutations performed by the functions?

For example, given:

- A `Pet` interface that includes a `feed()` method
- `Cat`, `Dog`, and `Hamster` objects that implement the `Pet` interface
- Functions that take an object implementing the `Pet` interface as input named `GivePetFood` (which calls `Pet.feed()`) and `GivePetABath` (which doesn't call `Pet.feed()`)

How could these entities be formally described such that one could perform a query along the lines of "find all functions that take an object implementing `Pet` and that will call `Pet.feed()` on that object"?

I imagine there must be design languages or some type of formal grammar that can describe the behavior of software in this way, but I've been unable to find anything useful. I'm aware of some annotation-based approaches (e.g., [SAL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects?view=msvc-170) has a rather limited [set of annotations to describe function behavior](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/annotating-function-behavior?view=msvc-170)), but these don't seem to be sufficiently versatile.

I'd prefer a solution that's language-agnostic, but language-specific examples would also be of interest.

Edit: to clarify a bit, I think I'm looking for something along the lines of [TLA+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLA%2B), but more limited in scope.

Comment: Certain programming languages like C# or Java provide a mechanism called Reflection which allows such queries - no need for inventing anything like a "formal grammer". Finding functions which (statically) call a certain other method, however, will involve to reverse analyse the IL code / byte code (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391188/make-a-call-graph-at-run-time-for-a-specific-method)) .This is still a Reflection task, but not a fully trivial one.

Comment: I've used reflection in both those languages and it wouldn't really be my first choice for this kind of modelling. Ideally, it would be nice to model these operations at the design stage without first having to produce a specific implementation.

Comment: The "design stage" where you make decisions about which function calls which other functions is the well known design stage called "coding" (see [Reeves, Code as Design](https://www.developerdotstar.com/mag/articles/reeves_design_main.html)). So the tool you need for doing the queries you described must operate on the code - which straight forward to Reflection.

Comment: My opinion is that, formally, coding is implementation, not design (both can certainly occur simultaneously and influence each other, though). I suspect [Leslie Lamport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_Lamport) (the creator of [TLA+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLA%2B)) and the creators of [Smithy](https://awslabs.github.io/smithy/) would agree. Unless a design is so low-level that it can only be expressed in one programming language, it must logically exist as a language-agnostic artifact (e.g., a design for a sorting algorithm could be implemented in FORTRAN, C++, Java, etc.).

Comment: @ReignofError, the problem is that expression and representation requires language. It is possible to acquire concepts without language, and it is possible to identify where the same concept appears in multiple languages. What's not possible is to express concepts without any language.

Answer (score 1):

Logically what you seem to be wanting is something like a simple diagram of a "call hierarchy", which you then analyse to determine whether a certain starting point leads to certain calls.

If all methods make all their subsidiary calls unconditionally, then the task would be simple. A "formal description" would simply involve describing which methods call which methods in turn.

The problem in practice is that programs incorporate not just sequential logic, but conditional and iterative logic.

You asked for a query that *"find[s] all functions that take an object implementing Pet and that **will** call Pet.feed() on that object"* (my emphasis added).

What if the method *may* call Pet.feed(), but does not *necessarily* do so?

In other words, what if your outer method does not simply bath or feed the pets, but bath them *repeatedly* until they smell clean, *and* feed them in between *if* they seem hungry? Now the call paths do not fall into a simple hierarchy, but represent a (potentially endless) variety of paths depending on the circumstances encountered.

What results do you want your analysis to return when it encounters such conditional or iterative logic that controls subsidiary calls (controlling whether they are made, how many times, and in what order including a weaved order)?

A formal description of *all* these possible behaviours is possibly called "source code", because when everything unnecessary is stripped away, it is fundamentally a high-level description of what calls are made, and what mutations occur, under what circumstances.

Comment: "What if the method may call Pet.feed(), but does not necessarily do so?" That's a different (but equally-valid) query. Both "will" and "may" queries could be of interest. As you (and Doc Brown in the comments on the question) have correctly pointed out, an analysis of source code can answer these questions; however, I'm looking for a solution that can model these relationships in a language-agnostic fashion. I'm beginning to suspect that the answer is probably just "use [TLA+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLA%2B)", but I'm still hoping there may be other options.

Comment: @ReignofError, unfortunately I'm not previously familiar with TLA+, but it looks rather like a "language" to me. I'm seriously concerned that there is some sort of misunderstanding on your part, and that a "language-agnostic model" is a synonym for a "description-agnostic description" - effectively a contradiction in terms. (1/2)

Comment: I can understand that you want a description free from the clutter of irrelevant matters, but I think you may be misapprehending how much clutter exists in the source code of mainstream languages, since the relationships you are trying to analyse are of fundamental importance to programmers, and mainstream languages are already designed to make their representation as clear as possible. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is UML: [Unified Modeling Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).

In UML you have structure diagrams, that describe classes, interfaces, their properties and their methods but also the overall structure of a program. There are other diagrams that describe how components are supposed to work or how the interact with the outside world.

[image]

A class structure diagram would look like this:

[image]

However, UML is not a machine data format, it does not define how this data is supposed to be stored in a file. To create UML diagrams, you either use a pen and a piece of paper or you use some UML design application, which defines its own storage format. Within such an application, a search as you desire could be possible (depending on the capabilities of the application).

Professional tools support describing UML diagrams in MOF: [Meta-Object Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-Object_Facility). And MOF data can be stored in the XMI format: [XML Metadata Interchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange).

If you have a tool that can export your UML diagrams as MOF to XMI, you could perform arbitrary data searches on that data if you have access to a XMI and MOF library. While all text-based XML, XMI is not really intended to be viewed in a text editor, as XMI will look like:

```xml
<XMI xmlns:UML="href://org.omg/UML/1.3" xmi.version="1.1">
    <XMI.header>
        <XMI.metamodel xmi.name="UML" xmi.version="1.3"/>
    </XMI.header>
    <XMI.content>
        <UML:Model name="PlantUML" xmi.id="model1">
            <UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
                <UML:Class name="class1" namespace="model1" xmi.id="cl1">
                    <UML:Classifier.feature>
                        <UML:Attribute name="field1" xmi.id="att6"/>
                    </UML:Classifier.feature>
                </UML:Class>
                <UML:Class name="class2" namespace="model1" xmi.id="cl2">
                    <UML:Classifier.feature/>
                </UML:Class>
                <UML:Class name="class3" namespace="model1" xmi.id="cl4">
                    <UML:Classifier.feature/>
                </UML:Class>
                <UML:Association namespace="model1" xmi.id="ass7">
                    <UML:Association.connection>
                        <UML:AssociationEnd association="ass7" type="cl2" xmi.id="end8">
                            <UML:AssociationEnd.participant>
                                <UML:Class xmi.idref="cl2"/>
                            </UML:AssociationEnd.participant>
                        </UML:AssociationEnd>
                        <UML:AssociationEnd association="ass7" type="cl1" xmi.id="end9">
                            <UML:AssociationEnd.participant>
                                <UML:Class xmi.idref="cl1"/>
                            </UML:AssociationEnd.participant>
                        </UML:AssociationEnd>
                    </UML:Association.connection>
                </UML:Association>
                <UML:Association namespace="model1" xmi.id="ass10">
                    <UML:Association.connection>
                        <UML:AssociationEnd association="ass10" type="cl2" xmi.id="end11">
                            <UML:AssociationEnd.participant>
                                <UML:Class xmi.idref="cl2"/>
                            </UML:AssociationEnd.participant>
                        </UML:AssociationEnd>
                        <UML:AssociationEnd association="ass10" type="cl4" xmi.id="end12">
                            <UML:AssociationEnd.participant>
                                <UML:Class xmi.idref="cl4"/>
                            </UML:AssociationEnd.participant>
                        </UML:AssociationEnd>
                    </UML:Association.connection>
                </UML:Association>
            </UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
        </UML:Model>
    </XMI.content>
</XMI>
```

The XML above describes the following UML diagram:

[image]

But there are tools that define there own data format, like PlantUML, which is way easier to handle, [here's](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuKhEIImkLW2JXWhLN0eAQPcfEIbSjLnG8Ls8d164RmJZ6tCvfEQbW0m00000) the same diagram again:

```
@startuml
class class1 {
  field
}
class1 - class2
class2 - class3
@enduml
```

Comment: I'm familiar with UML but I've never seen it used to model functions such that they can be queried to find those that perform certain types of mutations. For example, if one were to create sequence diagrams for every function, those diagrams could be manually inspected to identify mutations of a given type; the same sort of inspection could theoretically be done automatically, too, given a known representation format like PlantUML, but that doesn't seem like a natural use of them. Do you have a UML-based example of something along the lines of the example in my question?

Comment: @ReignofError Class structure diagrams tell you which methods take `Pet` as an argument and a communication diagram https://0cn.de/hab7 shows you who is calling `Pet.feed()` or a sequence diagram https://0cn.de/5nvp shows you who is feeding the pet (which implies calling `Pet.feed()`).

Comment: I understand that software relationships can be represented using UML diagrams, but those diagrams don't form a model that can be queried programmatically. For example, if there were hundreds of functions that take a `Pet`, it wouldn't be practical to go through all the associated diagrams manually to identify the functions that call `Pet.feed()`. Maybe there's an existing system that can parse PlantUML (or another text-based UML representation) for the purpose of performing queries of the sort described in my question?

Comment: @Mecki: to make this kind of information accessible by UML, the UML must be on the abstraction level of the code, and this for a whole system, which makes it pretty useless.